# Exception in GridViewAdapter

Tags: xml, android-logcat

In gridview adapter , I have the following code :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder view;
        LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            view = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.gridview_row, null);
            
            view.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            view.imgViewFlag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            
            convertView.setTag(view);
        }
        else
        {
            view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        
        view.txtViewTitle.setText(listCountry.get(position));
        view.imgViewFlag.setImageResource(listFlag.get(position));
        
        return convertView;
    }
```

According to my logic , the code should be ok . But I have an exception in my logcat . The error is described in the following :

[image]

In line no 72 , the line is : `view.imgViewFlag.setImageResource(listFlag.get(position));` How can this exception be resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if your listFlag is not empty and check your layout gridview_row is the id of imageview is same ..